# Adding position:sticky to element causes jumpy behaviour on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Problem:**
I have a title container element that starts off as 100vh to act as a landing page. When the user scrolls it should reduce the title container element to 15vh and stick it to the top of the window.
I've essentially done that but the transition isn't very smooth and jumps around when the user doesn't scroll heaps.

**Intended outcome:**
When the user scrolls at all, it should trigger the title element to reduce in size to 15vh and stick to the top of the window with a smooth transition.

**Things tried:**

- Adding additional transitions to the elements below the title element.
- changing the initial position of the title to 'absolute'
- Instead of adding in a class with position:sticky, I tried using position:absolute and top:0px.
- I have seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54931012/scroll-event-listener-position-sticky-element-that-changes-height-causes-jitt), but not sure how to apply it to mu issue.

I have tried to give an example below with the minimum amount of code.

```js
window.addEventListener(
  'scroll',
  function() {
    let scrollTop =
      window.pageYOffset ||
      (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body)
      .scrollTop;
    getPosition();
    console.log(getPosition());
    if (getPosition() <= 0) {
      this.document.getElementById('title').classList.add('header');
    } else {
      this.document.getElementById('title').classList.remove('header');
    }
  },
  false
);

function getPosition() {
  element = document.getElementById('topTitleMarker');
  var clientRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  return clientRect.top;
}
```

```css
.title {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
  -o-transition: all 1s linear;
  transition: all 1s linear;
  color: white;
}

.header {
  top: 0px;
  height: 15vh;
  position: sticky;
}

body {
  background-color: white;
  height: 500vh;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
  /*   overflow: hidden; */
}

.topTitleMarker {
  top: 1px;
  position: absolute;
}

.test {
  margin-top: 15vh;
}
```

```html
<div id='title' class="title">TITLE</div>
<div id='topTitleMarker' class="topTitleMarker"></div>
<div class="test">TEST</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/iamstevenhale/pen/MWrMejE)

Comment: I'm not sure why you are setting and unsetting position: sticky - the body has a margin so when unstuck header is down a bit from the top of the viewport and when it has position sticky it 'jumps' to the top. I don't know whether that is the phenomenon you are describing or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problems

I think the jerkiness in the scrolling was because of the `.topTitleMarker` was referenced as the top of scrolling element with `.getBoundingClientRect().top` and the `transition` was based on the height of `.title` when it increases at 100vh but there isn't a transition for when `.title` shrinks. Moreover, `transition` is a process heavy animation, but your animation is a simple one so no worries there.

### Changes

**JavaScript**

- Removed `scrollTop` -- it wasn't being used
- Moved and consolidated `getPosition()` over to the event handler
- Also changed the reference element for `.getBoundingClientRect().top` from
  `.topTitleMarker` to `<h1>` (in OP it's `.title`)

**CSS**

- Removed `transition` from `<h1>`
- Added `animation: grow 1s forwards ease-out;` to `<h1>`
- Added `animation: shrink 1s forwards ease-out;` to `.header`
- For smoother animation `animation` and `@keyframes` are used for shrinking and growing of `<h1>`

**HTML**

- Removed everything from OP and added a `<h1>`

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', headerHeight);

function headerHeight(event) {
  const title = document.querySelector('h1');
  if (title.getBoundingClientRect().top <= 0) {
    title.classList.add('header');
  } else {
    title.classList.remove('header');
  }
};
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@300;700&display=swap');

html {
  font: 300 2ch/1.25 'Titillium Web';
}

body {
  height: 500vh;
}

h1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  animation: grow 1s forwards ease-out;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  height: 15vh;
  animation: shrink 1s forwards ease-out;
}

@keyframes grow {
  0% {
    height: 15vh
  }
  100% {
    height: 100vh
  }
}

@keyframes shrink {
  0% {
    height: 100vh
  }
  100% {
    height: 15vh
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>TITLE</h1>
```

Comment: Border bottom: white to see the end of the screen.
Thanks, works a charm. You're a wizard :)